# Upload video to jw player account using Laravel

Tags: php, video, laravel-5, jwplayer

I want to add video file or video URL to jwplayer in my laravel 5.2 project but i didn't found it's any package or library yet. It's documentation is very difficult to understand for me as I never worked on jwplayer before. My requirement is to upload video to jwplayer and amazon s3 bucket. It's uploading to s3 bucket but I'm stuck at jwplayer. Any guide or example will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
Use this code...  


  <?php
    
    require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
    
    function get_parts_count($file) {
        // 5 MB is the minimum size of an upload part, per https://developer.jwplayer.com/jwplayer/docs/stream-multipart-resumable-upload
        $minimum_part_size = 5 * 1024 * 1024; 
        $size = filesize($file);
        return (floor($size / $minimum_part_size) + 1);
    }
    
    $secret = $_ENV('JWPLATFORM_API_SECRET');
    $site_id = $_ENV('JWPLATFORM_SITE_ID');
    
    $jwplatform_api = new Jwplayer\JwplatformClient($secret);
    
    $target_file = 'examples/test.mp4';
    $params = array();
    $params['metadata'] = array();
    $params['metadata']['title'] = 'PHP API Test Upload';
    $params['metadata']['description'] = 'Video description here';
    $params['upload'] = array();
    $params['upload']['method'] = 'multipart';
    
    $create_response = json_encode($jwplatform_api->Media->create($site_id, $params));
    
    print_r($create_response);
    print("\n");
    
    $decoded = json_decode(json_decode(trim($create_response), true), true);
    $upload_id = $decoded['upload_id'];
    $upload_token = $decoded['upload_token'];
    $media_id = $decoded['id'];
    
    $parts_count = get_parts_count($target_file);
    $upload_parts_url = "https://api.jwplayer.com/v2/uploads/$upload_id/parts?page=1&page_length=$parts_count";
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $upload_parts_url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Authorization: Bearer ' . $upload_token,
        ),
    ));
    
    $upload_parts_response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    
    $upload_parts_response_object = json_decode($upload_parts_response);
    print_r($upload_parts_response_object);
    print("\n");
    
    $upload_url_parts = $upload_parts_response_object->parts;
    // 5 MB is the minimum size of an upload part, per https://developer.jwplayer.com/jwplayer/docs/stream-multipart-resumable-upload
    $buffer = (1024 * 1024) * 5; 
    if (count($upload_url_parts) > 0) {
        $file_handle = fopen($target_file, 'rb');
        foreach($upload_url_parts as $upload_url_parts_key => $upload_url_parts_value) {
            $upload_bytes_url = $upload_url_parts_value -> upload_link;
            $file_part = fread($file_handle, $buffer);
            $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $upload_bytes_url);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $file_part);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                'Content-Type:'
            ));
            $upload_bytes_response = curl_exec($curl);
            print_r($upload_bytes_response);
            print("\n");
        }
        fclose($file_handle);
    
        $complete_upload_url = "https://api.jwplayer.com/v2/uploads/$upload_id/complete";
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $complete_upload_url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'PUT',
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                'Authorization: Bearer ' . $upload_token,
            ),
        ));
        $complete_upload_response = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        $complete_upload_response_object = json_decode($complete_upload_response);
        print_r($complete_upload_response_object);
        print("\n");
    }
    
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell Laravel is a PHP framework and it shouldn't be a problem to use the JW Player APIs within that. Have you checked the documentation here: 
https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-platform/reference/v1/s3_uploads.html

There are also a couple of script examples (PHP and Python) that you can use here to get started:
https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-platform/

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple steps in uploading a video on jwplayer:-

```
$apiKey = env('jw_player_apikey');
$apiV2Secret = env('jw_player_secretkey);

// Step1.  for getting upload_token and upload_id
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, [
 CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.jwplayer.com/v2/sites/$apiKey/media/",
 CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
 CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
 CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
 CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
 CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
 CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
 CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\"upload\":{\"method\":\"multipart\"},\"metadata\":{\"title\":\"$r->title\",\"description\":\"My media description\"}}",
 CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
   "Accept: application/json",
   "Authorization: $apiV2Secret",
   "Content-Type: application/json"
 ],
]);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    return response()->json(['status'=>'error']);
} else {
   $response=json_decode($response);

   // Step2. For getting upload_link
   $curl1 = curl_init();
   curl_setopt_array($curl1, [
       CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.jwplayer.com/v2/uploads/$response->upload_id/parts?page=1&page_length=1",
       CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
       CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
       CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
       CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
       CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
       CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
       CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
       "Accept: application/json",
       "Authorization: Bearer ".$response->upload_token,
       "Content-Type: application/json"
       ],
   ]);

   $response1 = curl_exec($curl1);
   $err1 = curl_error($curl1);
   curl_close($curl1);

   if ($err1) {
    return response()->json(['status'=>'error']);
   } 
   else {
       $response1=json_decode($response1);
       $url = $response1->parts[0]->upload_link;

       // Step4. For uploading parts
       $curl2 = curl_init($url);
       curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
       curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, TRUE);
       curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
       curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:'));

       $file = $r->file('video');
       $handle = fopen($file, "r");
       $data = fread($handle, filesize($file));
       curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
       $resp = curl_exec($curl2);
       $err2 = curl_error($curl2);
       curl_close($curl2);
       if ($err2) {
        return response()->json(['status'=>'error']);
    } 
       else {

           // Step 5. to complete the upload
           $curl3 = curl_init();
           curl_setopt_array($curl3, [
             CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.jwplayer.com/v2/uploads/".$response->upload_id."/complete",
             CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
             CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
             CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
             CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
             CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
             CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "PUT",
             CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
               "Authorization: Bearer ".$response->upload_token,
               "Content-Type: application/json"
             ],
           ]);
           
           $response3 = curl_exec($curl3);
           $err3 = curl_error($curl3);
           
           curl_close($curl3);
           
           if ($err3) {
            return response()->json(['status'=>'error']);
        } else {
               // Step 6. Get uploaded video details
               $curl6 = curl_init();
               curl_setopt_array($curl6, [
               CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.jwplayer.com/v2/sites/$apiKey/media/$response->id",
               CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
               CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
               CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
               CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
               CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
               CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
               CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
                   "Authorization: Bearer $apiV2Secret",
                   "Content-Type: application/json"
               ],
               ]);
               
               $response6 = curl_exec($curl6);
               $err6 = curl_error($curl6);
               
               curl_close($curl6);
               
               if ($err6) {
                return response()->json(['status'=>'error']);
            } else {

                  $video_response=json_decode($response6);    

                  //get video id from the response
                  if($this->check_count($video_response)>0){

                    //insert video detail in database
                    $insert=new videos();
                    $insert->jw_id=$video_response->id;
                    $insert->save();
                    if ($insert) {
                        return response()->json(['status'=>'success']);
                    } else {
                        return response()->json(['status'=>'error','message'=>"Fail to upload video, Please try again!!"]);
                    }
                  }
                  else{
                    return response()->json(['status'=>'error','message'=>"Fail to upload video, Please try again!!"]);
                }
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

The above code doc was received from ***JW player*** official. It's working on my side. Hope it helps you too.